# find files and delete by filename parameter

Tags: bash, duplicates

I have a folder with lots of images. In this folder are subfolders containing high resolution images. Images can be .png, .jpg or .gif.
Some images are duplicates called **a.jpg** and **a.hi.jpg** or **a.b.c.gif** and **a.b.c.hi.gif**. File names are always different, the will be never a.gif, a.jpg or a.png. I guess i have not to take care of extension.
These are the same images with different resolution.

Now i want to write a script to delete all lower resolution images. But there are files that do not have high resolution like b.png. So i want to delete only if there is a high resolution image too.

I guess i have to do something like this, but can't figure out how exactly.

```
find . -type f -name "*" if {FILENAME%hi*} =2 --delete smallest else keep file
```

Could anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following could do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -d '' hi
do
    d=$(dirname "$hi")
    b=$(basename "$hi")
    low="${b//.hi./}"
    [[ -e "$d/$low" ]] && echo rm -- "$d/$low"  #dry run - if satisfied, remove the echo
done < <(find /some/path -type f -name \*.hi.\* -print0)
```

how it works:

- finds all files with `.hi.` in their names. (not only images, you can extend the `find` be more restrictive
- for all found images

  - get the directory, where is he
  - and get the name of the file (without directory)
  - in the name, remove all occurences of the string `.hi.` (aka make the "lowres" name
  - check the existence of the lowres image
  - delete if exists.

Comment: thanks. could have never figures something like this out. But i get syntax error unexpected word "<" and same line "`done < < (find . type f -name \*.hi.\* -print0)'. Any clue why?

Comment: are sure that you copied ok? e.g. is here a space between `< <(`? (also added one missing pair of `""`.

Comment: ... also added the shebang - it is designed for `bash`.

Comment: yes, i copied exactly your code. maybe my fault putting it into text file called test.sh and putting #!/bin/bash at beginning? running via sh test.sh

Comment: run as `bash test.sh` or `chmod 755 test.sh` and `./test.sh`

Comment: thanks for your help. i am sorry to tell that i now get no error, but also no files found. just nothing happens. tried to do test with video files changing scrip from "hi" to "720p" but also no luck "720p not valid". with hi no error, but no results.

Comment: @wombat hm.. so, im sorry can't help. it works for me in my test images. maybe, try run the script as `bash -x test.sh` (note the `-x`) and watch what happens.

Comment: thank you, now it works. had to change "low="${b//.hi./}"" to "low="${b//.hi/}"". with the extra dot i got ajpg instead of a.jpg. Thanks for your great help

Comment: yw & Enjoy the script :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bash` [extended glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) features for this, which you can enable first by

```
shopt -s extglob
```

and using the pattern

```
!(pattern-list)
Matches anything except one of the given patterns.
```

Now to store the files not containing the string `hi`

```
shopt -s extglob
fileList=()

fileList+=( !(*hi*).jpg )
fileList+=( !(*hi*).gif )
fileList+=( !(*hi*).png )
```

You can print once the array to see if it lists all the files you need as

```
printf "%s\n" "${fileList[@]}"
```

and to delete those files do

```
for eachfile in "${fileList[@]}"; do
    rm -v -- "$eachfile"
done
```

(or) as Benjamin.W suggested in comments below, do

```
rm -v -- "@{fileList[@]}"
```

Comment: I thought the high resolution pictures are supposed to be kept, not deleted.

Comment: Also, the way you use `@(*hi*).jpg` is the same as just writing `*hi*.jpg`. You could shorten to `*hi*.@(jpg|gif|png)`, though.

Comment: And to delete the files, you can just use `rm -v -- "@{fileList[@]}"` instead of a loop.

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes, but... :) you can get _argument length exceeded_ or somewhat like is called when the arg-length is too long. Using the `loop` it is safe... (or me wrong?)

Comment: Oh, I see. Don't you want "does NOT match the pattern", `!()`? As in `fileList=(!(*hi*).@(jpg|gif|png))`?

Comment: @BenjaminW.: OP does not want the files having the pattern `hi` in the names, see my answer edit history, I initially thought that way too!

Comment: Yes, but your command `@()` includes them. I think you meant `!()`.

Comment: @Inian the OP wants _delete all lower resolution images._. The images with `.hi.` are high resolution. (at least it is how me understand the qst). :)

Comment: @jm666: Updated now! looks like I had a brain-fade! initially did this `!` part, but somehow changed it and now reverted back! Thanks! @Benjamin.W

Answer (score -1):

> Now i want to write a script to delete all lower resolution images

This script could be used for that:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -iname '*.hi.png' -or -iname '*.hi.gif' -or -iname '*.hi.jpg' | while read F; do LOWRES="$(echo "$F" | rev | cut -c7- | rev)$(echo "$F" | rev | cut -c 1-3 | rev)"; if [ -f "$LOWRES" ]; then echo rm -fv -- "$LOWRES"; fi; done
```

You can run it to see what files will be removed first. If you're ok with results then remove `echo` before `rm` command.

Here is the non-one line version, but a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

find /path/to/dir -type f -iname '*.hi.png' -or -iname '*.hi.gif' -or -iname '*.hi.jpg' |
    while read F; do
        NAME="$(echo "$F" | rev | cut -c7- | rev)"
        EXTENSION="$(echo "$F" | rev | cut -c 1-3 | rev)"
        LOWRES="$NAME$EXTENSION"
        if [ -f "$LOWRES" ]; then
            echo rm -fv -- "$LOWRES"
        fi
    done
```